# Unable to see data in HTML status report

Tags: html, salesforce-classic, report-chart, email-tracking

I have a process where on insertion of a record in the custom table, an email is triggered to the customer. To achieve this we created a workflow and an HTML email template which triggers the email. The requirement is now to track the email, create a report and display the same.
To achieve that I have enabled email tracking in activity settings.

[image]

After this, I tried to create the HTML status report from reports. But the data to viewed is 0 records

[image]

I read that you can view the emails from the user that sends the email. Hence I might be seeing 0 records. So I created the same report through Admin user but still the same issue. I am not sure which user would send the mail. The user which created the workflow or the user which created the email template.

Help here would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is very late.

It is because this report only shows the records when the logged In user send an email.
I am also facing same issue. I want to show all Emails Status report. But as per below documentation it will work for logged in user is a sender.
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000321515&type=1

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/178729)